# How can I replace all instances of a URL using javascript ( like in an image's src, or as a webpage itself)?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to create be able to redirect this one image that is on multiple different spots on a site into a new image. They all share the same url. If anyone knows how I can accomplish this, thank you!

I tried finding the image ids to just use the GetElementById() method to get at it, but because they're being drawn onto a canvas I can't get there. I tried finding some resources that explained how to do this, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: A canvas is just pixels drawn to the screen. You cant change the image after the fact you need to change the code that draws to the canvas. Or remove the canvas element entirely and draw a new on with the new image.

Comment: Oh, okay. I just realized that I forgot to mention that I had used an extension before to do this, and wanted to replicate what it had done, now that it is making you pay a fee to do what I need to do. The way it worked was replacing the urls, here's its link: https://www.requestly.in/ .

Comment: so is your problem resolved? If so I would add an answer with more detail.

Comment: No, it's not resolved yet. I want to know how to redirect all instances of a URL with javascript. It doesn't matter really where it is, I don't think?

Comment: Also, it would be done before the page loads with like an extension, so that it loads my image into the canvas, and not the other image.